# Precise positioning in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an app where I need an image to be positioned precisely at a certain x and y position.The image will randomly be moving to new positions.

I cannot see how to accomplish this.

Comment: What Layout do you use? AbsoluteLayout, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout? What attributes has your image? Do you use dp (density independent pixels)? Give us some insight!

Comment: Using LinearLayout.I I use DP.Have not tried much cause I am stuck without a clue.I was going to try AbsoluteLayout but heard it was deprecated.

Comment: abosulte still exist but is marked deprecated so I guess soon it won't be supported anymore. I put the code to create your own views but as you'll see it is annoying process and you have to add a lot more code to make it look nice whatever the size of the screen ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if android encourages to use layouts for this (since there is several size, dimensions quality resolutions of screens with layouts you'll have the same aspect on all devices).

there is 2 other ways you can do this

1) change everything for an opengl view ^^ but thats taking out a canon to get a mosquito.

2) Create your own view, override the onDraw(canvas) and do your own drawing there.

I have to warn you it get really tedious to get all the drawings position correctly on the Canvas

---

edit
here is some code to get you started on creating your views programatically, I also added the touch test.

(one thing I want to draw your attention: there is a image.getWidth() (actual size of the picture) and a image.getScaledWidth(canvas) which give you the size of the element in dp which means how big it will appear on the screen)

```
public class MainMenuView extends PixelRainView{
    private Bitmap bmpPlay = null;
    private float playLeft = 0;
    private float playRight = 0;
    private float playBottom = 0;
    private float playTop = 0;

    public MainMenuView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context,attrs);
    }



    @Override
    public void unLoadBitmaps() {
        super.unLoadBitmaps();
        if(bmpPlay != null){
            bmpPlay.recycle();
            bmpPlay = null;
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(bmpPlay == null){
            bmpPlay = getBitmapFromRessourceID(R.drawable.play_bt);
            playLeft = (this.getWidth()-bmpPlay.getScaledWidth(canvas))/2; 
            playRight = playLeft + bmpPlay.getScaledWidth(canvas);
            playTop = (this.getHeight()-bmpPlay.getScaledHeight(canvas))/2;
            playBottom = playTop+bmpPlay.getScaledHeight(canvas);
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmpPlay,playLeft, playTop, null);

        }       
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            //test central button
            if(x>playLeft && x<playRight && y<playBottom && y>playTop){
                Log.e("jason", "touched play");
                PixelRainView.changeView(R.layout.composedlayoutgroup);
            }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd rather keep it simple heh.I know 0 opengl and the second option seems like you said tedious.

Comment: to my knowledge its the only way to use (x,y) to place elements on android

Comment: Oh ok you know of any tutorials?

Comment: actually I never looked for a tutorial I sort of figured it out lol but I added to my post a version that draws one button